# ¿Cuáles son los problemas de la recursión?

Tags: funciones, recursión

he estado investigando acerca de las funciones recursivas y me gustaría saber que inconvenientes, además del stack overflow, presentan las funciones recursivas.

Gracias.

Comment: eso mas que un problema seria un error en la funcion.. a que te referis con problemas? errores comunes?

Comment: Como desventajas de las funciones recursivas

Answer (score 0):

Uno de los principales problemas es el consumo de memoria ya que mientras mas profunda este la recursividad mas memoria gastara, lo que hace la recursividad en una función es llamarse así misma para realizar una operación definiendo con un condición final ya que si no se agrega dicha condición esta continuara llamándose de forma infinita el cual puede ser otro de los problemas el cual ocasione que se cicle y terminar por consumir toda la memoria disponible, por lo anterior mencionado sobre el consuma memoria es que cunado va llamándose se crea una copia de sus variables y parámetros en memoria las veces que avance en profundidad.

Ejemplo:

```
void incremento(int i) {
      System.out.println(i);
      if(i < 1000) {
            incremento(i + 1);
      }
}
```

En el ejemplo anterior la función va incrementando en 1 un valor dado, su profundidad va de acuerdo a su valor inicial y finaliza al llegar a 1000

Comment: Una copia de la misma funcion? o una copia de los parametros?

Comment: @gbianchi una copia de sus variables y parámetros, gracias por la observación